# ssh tail output lines only with keyword

Tags: ssh, tail

I'm trying to tail a large file in an ssh command prompt, but I need to filter it so it only displays lines that contain a particular keyword in them.

I'm using this command currently to tail.

```
# tail /usr/local/apache/logs/access_log
```

If possible please let me know what I would add to this command to accomplish this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can pipe the output of `tail` and use `grep`.  To

> filter so it only displays lines that contain a particular keyword in them

you could do:

```
tail /usr/local/apache/logs/access_log | grep "keyword"
```

where you'd replace `keyword` with your keyword.